# Transform view volume from one view into another

Tags: opengl, projection-matrix, frustum, matrix-transform

So i have an object in world space and two views A and B which display the scene with different camera setups. I want to transform the view volume (near plane) from view A into view B so i can have something like an overview and detail. What transformations do i have to apply to the points of view A's frustums near plane to display it in view B?

Answer (score 1):

Let *V_a* be the non-singular, invertible transformation from world space into view space *A*.
Let *V_b* be the non-singular, invertible transformation from world space into view space *B*. Then the transformation from space A to B is

T_A→B: r ↦ V_b · inverse(V_a) · r